# Is it possible to use the mvc-mini-profiler with typed datasets?

Tags: asp.net, mvc-mini-profiler

I've been experimenting with using mvc-mini-profiler on a ASP.NET website.  All of the request profiling works perfectly, but now I'm trying to see if there is a way to hook it into our database calls.

All of our database calls on our website are done by using typed datasets (.xsd files) with table and query table adapters. Is it possible to somehow hook in the mvc-mini-profiler to these datasets?

I understand that you would typically get some sort of dbconnection (SqlConnection, etc.) and then wrap that with the profiler's ProfiledDbConnection. I just don't know how to do this with a dataset, is it even possible?

Note: changing from using datasets to linq2sql or some other way would not really be feasible as this is a rather large project that has been around for some time.

**Example database call**

```
DAL_ClientTableAdapters.ClientTableAdapter tba = new DAL_ClientTableAdapters.ClientTableAdapter();
DAL_Client.ClientDataTable dt = tba.GetData();
```

Where there is a DAL_Client.xsd file containing a table adapter called `Client` which uses a connection string defined in the web.config

Comment: How are you loading the datasets - [DataSet.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab24tfx.aspx)? Where's the IDataReader coming from - your own DB connection? Can't you just used a profiled connection for that?

Comment: No, there is a .xsd file.  I just get the data like so: `DAL_ClientTableAdapters.ClientTableAdapter tba = new DAL_ClientTableAdapters.ClientTableAdapter();
                DAL_Client.ClientDataTable dt = tba.GetData();`  It is a typed dataset, with the connection in a connectionString in the web.config.

Comment: @rup Updated question with comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Darin Dimitrov pointed out, you can't really do it. You can modify the code generator to set the TableAdapter's `Connection` property public, so you could pass in your own Connection. But `SqlConnection` is a **sealed** class, so you can't extend it by adding profiling hooks to it...

### Possible workarounds:

1. You can get basic timing information by add profiling "steps" around your db calls. But you get no special highlighting in the UI, total SQL time, or details about the command(s) and parameter(s) of the query like you get for regular db calls. If these are important, I think you could extend the miniprofiler code to help with timings. I think Something like this:

   ```
   DAL_ClientTableAdapters.ClientTableAdapter tba = new DAL_ClientTableAdapters.ClientTableAdapter();
   DAL_Client.ClientDataTable dt = null;
   //if you are not familiar with miniprofiler Steps, this adds the elapsed time between the curly braces to your timing information
   using(MiniProfiler.StepStatic("Executing GetData() from 'Client' table")) {
       dt = tba.GetData();
   }
   ```

   Here is what you would get:
   [image: Basic timing information about your db call]
2. Try to change the code generator to add `DbConnection` into the generated files instead of `SqlConnection`. Don't know if the typed datasets, or your code uses anything SqlConnection specific, but sound pretty risky for an old and large project...
3. Try to use [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) to insert profiling hooks to SqlConnection. OK, not exactly serious about this...

Comment: Wrapping the database calls to get their timing looks like the best work around approach until we convert these typed datasets to linq2sql. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this scenario is not supported. When you generate a strongly typed Table Adapter, the Visual Studio Designer automatically generate classes for which specific data access classes are used: SqlConnection, SqlCommand, ... The way mini-profiler works is that it wraps the actual underlying connection in a `ProfiledDbConnection`. This class derives from `DbConnection` and you cannot pass it to the table adapter since it relies on `SqlConnection`.

The mini profiler can be used with Data Access Layers that do not rely on a hardcoded specific implementation of a DbConnection but work with abstractions and providers.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I figured it wasn't really possibly but wanted to ask just in case I was overlooking something.